# introduction of system biology to bench biologists

Tags: book-recommendation, systems-biology

I am trained as a bench biologist and I want to learn about system biology and introduce a system biology type of analysis into my study. Can somebody recommend books and websites about system biology for biologists?

Comment: Don't have any good suggestions, but I suspect that the answer will depend critically on how strong your math background is. Can you add a few details about that? i.e., how familiar are you with calculus, differential equations, and linear algebra (matrices)?

Comment: "Systems biology" is an incredibly broad category.